# SimSun Regular font problems

Tags: rdlc, truetype

I developed RDLC report rendered with pdf by using SimSun font. My web sever uses SimSun font 5.00.  The problem is some of my clients cannot see the correct words.  The report displays as garbage.  But some of them can see the correct words.  And I tested and found that the correct words are displayed in window where SimSum font 2.11 or 3.03 exists.  And if the window installed SimSum 5.03 font, incorrect words are displayed.  But I don't know exactly which SimSun font versions are compatible with version 5.00.  Anyone can tell me, please?